# Roll multiple dice at same time given num of sides and num of dice from the user

Tags: python

The goal I have is to make a function to roll multiple dice at the same time.
The user enters how many sides are on the dice(between 2-20 inclusive) and the user enters how many dice to use(BETWEEN 3 AND 6).

The program then calculates a random number between 1 and the # of sides the user entered to generate the side(and score) the dice landed on. And will display the score(side) of each dice that was generated.

I cannot figure out how to put it together properly and have been trying other code from similar questions but no luck yet.

**I have some loops to validate the input is in the range but i removed it to keep it short.**

Output example

```
Enter # of faces [2,20]: 10

Enter # of dice [3,6]: 4

You have rolled: [9, 3, 8, 8]
```

Code:

```
face = int( input( "how many sides are on your die? enter a number between 2-20 inclusive: "))
number_of_dice = int( input( "How many dice are you using? Must be between 3-6 inclusive" ) )

def roll_die():
    for _ in range(rolls):
        print random.randint(1, face)
```

Comment: Where is `rolls`? Where do you use `number_of_dice`?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than printing the dice roll, add it to a list.

```py
import random

faces = int(input("How many sides on a die? ")
num_dice = int(input("How many dice? ")

rolls = []
for die in range(num_dice):
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, faces)
    rolls.append(dice_roll)

print("You have rolled: " + str(rolls))
```

Then you can make small improvements to readability, like refactoring this

```py
rolls = []
for die in range(num_dice):
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, faces)
    rolls.append(dice_roll)
```

Into this

```py
rolls = [random.randint(1, faces) for _ in range(num_dice)]
```

or even using string formatting or f-strings for the print.

```py
print("You have rolled: {}".format(rolls))
#  or
print(f"You have rolled: {rolls}")
```